# Use of SSA (Single Static Assignment) while dynamic analysis

Tags: dynamic-analysis

I have read that dynamic instrumentation can be done using tools like PIN or Valgrind. However Valgrind provides intermediate representation and converts the binary into SSA which makes it more convenient to perform binary analysis. Could anyone please explain why using an SSA form is more convenient. Why is it difficult to perform dynamic analysis using PIN without an Intermediate representation?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering this questions will require a lot more space than what is provided. I rather point you to the best references you can find in order to deeply understand the requirement for `SSA`.

First, start with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) so that you get familiarized with the basic structure and building blocks of `SSA` (Phi functions, ...). Then, move to [this](http://grothoff.org/christian/teaching/2007/3353/papers/ssa.pdf) reference article published in 1991, which is a bit more hairy than the Wikipedia article.

If you want a more detailed document, though incomplete, read [this](http://ssabook.gforge.inria.fr/latest/book.pdf) book.
It covers a wide range of algorithms for construction/destruction and also analysis.

If you wish a long/detailed answer, let me know so that I can write a proper one.

Comment: Thank you @yaspr for the references, I would go over and read them. Also it would help me a lot if you could mention the cons of doing dynamic taint analysis without an Intermediate Representation.